# General custom serializers.DateField with supporting date format

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, serialization

I want to create general custom field to read str dates and convert it to date with passed format.

So, I want something like this:

```
date_field = CustomDateField(format=custom_format)
```

Is it possible? I hope so

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: @JPG tried what?

Comment: the code that you have added here

Comment: @JPG no, I don't know how to make it. That's why I'm asking :)